# SqueezeNet Problems

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

im trying to install squeezeNet,
These are the instructions

```
SqueezeNet_v1.0/train_val.prototxt          #model architecture
SqueezeNet_v1.0/solver.prototxt             #additional training details (learning rate schedule, etc.)
SqueezeNet_v1.0/squeezenet_v1.0.caffemodel  #pretrained model parameters
```

When running the first command,i get this error,I have no idea what to do?

```
decentmakeover@DecentMakeover:~/caffe-master$ ./build/tools/caffe 
train -solver SqueezeNet/SqueezeNet_v1.0/train_val.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:291] Error parsing 
text-format caffe.SolverParameter: 8:7: Message type 
"caffe.SolverParameter" has no field named "layer".
F0718 20:10:12.568349 10005 upgrade_proto.cpp:1101] Check failed: 
ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse 
SolverParameter file: SqueezeNet/SqueezeNet_v1.0/train_val.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fb3dac635cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fb3dac65433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fb3dac6315b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fb3dac65e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fb3db033ef1  caffe::ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie()
    @           0x40a4d8  train()
    @           0x4072f8  main
    @     0x7fb3d92ec830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x407bc9  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: The SqueezeNet implementation is based on Caffe, and can be run as you would run any other Caffe network. It's quite easy to learn about that. You could refer to [this helpful tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html).

Comment: why the down vote-if things were really easy i wouldnt waste time,typing the question and waiting for other people to answer and get on with my work-

Comment: I did not downvote. This was a suggestion based on my own experience, I started using Caffe very recently. The answers you have got so far will solve your current problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`train_val.prototxt` is the topology description.  This is good only for the `model` parameter, as in the `caffe test` command.

For the `caffe train` command, you use the `solver` option (as you did), but you have to supply the name of the `solver.prototxt` file (which is likely "solver.prototxt").

**ADDED CLARIFICATION**

You should have a solver file that starts vaguely like the one below.  Make sure that your path to the solver file *and* the `net:` path below are accurate.

```
net: "/home/prune/caffe/models/googlenet_v1/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 4000
display: 50
average_loss: 50
base_lr: 0.01
```

Comment: Hi Prune ,-But when i do run the solver command,which is  ./build/tools/caffe train -solver SqueezeNet/SqueezeNet_v1.0/solver.prototxt, i get file not found -train_val.prototxt-

Comment: @Ryan make sure that the path to `'train_val.prototxt'`, **written in** `'solver.prototxt'` is correct and points to the right location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the `'solver.prototxt'` as an input argument for `caffe train` and not the `'train_val.prototxt`